# When I get firebase data and I log it it returns the document file but when I output it it returns a promise

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have been working with firebase and am having trouble with this code.

The goal of the code is to get the document data with the document id.

```
  const getPostData = async (postId) => {
    const postData = await getDoc(doc(db, 'posts', postId));
    console.log(postData.data()); // Returns the document data
    return postData.data();
  }
  const postData = getPostData(id);
  console.log(postData) // Returns a promise
```

I am extremely confused because I return the document data which when I log gives me the actual document data but when I set it as a variable it does not do the same.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a function like `async`, it returns a `Promise` automatically. So the problem is in logic.

What happens:

- You call `getPostData`
- It is an `async` function, so, its return is `Promise`
- The larger scope is not an `async` scope, so the `console.log` is executed right after, not waiting for the execution of what is inside `getPostData`
- `console.log` returns a `Promise`

Try something like:

```
const [postData, setPostData]= useState()

const getPostData = async (postId) => {
  const postData = await getDoc(doc(db, 'posts', postId));
  if (postData.exists()) {
    console.log(postData.data()); // Returns the document data
    setPostData(postData.data());
  } else {
    console.log("No posts!");
  }
}
...
getPostData(id);
...
console.log(postData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you've marked `getPostData` as `async` it returns a `Promise` and not an immediate value.

To get the value from the promise when calling `getPostData`, you can either use `then()`:

```
getPostData(id).then((postData) => {
  console.log(postData)
})
```

Or you can use `await`:

```
const postData = await getPostData(id);
console.log(postData)
```